# How can I delete a branch named '-delete'?

Tags: git, command-line-interface, branch

I have accidentally created a local branch called -delete

When I try to run commands to delete the branch using

```
git branch -d -delete

git branch -D -delete

git branch --delete -delete
```

It does not work and gives the error message back that says this:

```
error: did you mean `--delete` (with two dashes ?)
```

How can I delete the '-delete' branch?

Answer (score 3):

`git branch` also honors the `--` convention : if you pass `--` alone as an argument on the command line, anything after that will not be interpreted as an option.

Starting from @torek's setup in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71685428/86072) :

```
$ git branch delete && mv .git/refs/heads/delete .git/refs/heads/-delete
$ git branch
  -delete
* master

$ git branch -d -delete     # fails
error: did you mean `--delete` (with two dashes)?

$ git branch -d -- -delete  # works
Deleted branch -delete (was cec927c).

$ git branch
* master
```

Answer (score 2):

No user-oriented Git command should have let you *create* that branch name in the first place (I had to resort to trickery to set up the condition myself, as I didn't think to use `git update-ref` right off), but once you have it, the way to get rid of the bad name is to use `git update-ref`:

```
git update-ref -d refs/heads/-delete
```

Here's my example:

```
$ git branch delete
$ mv .git/refs/heads/delete .git/refs/heads/-delete
$ git branch
  -delete
  diff-merge-base
* master
$ git branch -d -delete
error: did you mean `--delete` (with two dashes)?
$ git update-ref -d refs/heads/-delete
$ git branch
  diff-merge-base
* master
```

Comment: You can create it with update-ref, `git update-ref refs/heads/-delete HEAD`. Then of course `git update-ref -d refs/heads/-delete`.

Comment: Oddly enough. the -delete branch is still there... I am also surprised I created the branch in the first place. I'm sure I ran something simple along the lines of 'git br -delete'. Could it be some Eslint config? It is a huge codebase.

Comment: @jthill: ah, yes, of course. I was experimenting with "user oriented" ones first and didn't think to use it to create the branch, since nobody would use `git update-ref` directly like that.

Comment: @Jake.K: eslint shouldn't be going around creating branch names in the first place.

Comment: Am I going to have to break out my best Mel Blanc voice here?

Comment: @jthill: Rabbit season! Duck season! Elmer season!

Comment: Heh. I was going for "He don't know me vewy well, do he?"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The only way that I found was to delete it by git GUI.

1- Right click in your project directory and then click on git GUI here
2- From the navbar click on branch then click on delete
3- choose the branch from the local branches box and the second box below, then click on the delete

Done
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jK1y.png)